# How to generate a receipt number

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

On Stack Overflow, I found the question *[Generate a receipt number in this range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941886/generate-a-receipt-number-in-this-range)*.

In answers (from Adam Maras) I find this code (very interesting for me):

```
Private Const FirstReceiptNumber As String = "GA00000"

Public Function GenerateReceiptNumber(ByVal lastNumber As String) As String

    If lastNumber.Length <> 7 Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Incorrect length", "lastNumber")
    End If

    If lastNumber.StartsWith("G") = False Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Incorrect start character", "lastNumber")
    End If

    Dim letterPortion As Char = lastNumber.Chars(1)

    If letterPortion < "A"c Or letterPortion > "Z"c Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Non-letter second character", "lastNumber")
    End If

    If letterPortion = "I"c Or letterPortion = "O"c Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid second character", "lastNumber")
    End If

    Dim numericPortionString As String = lastNumber.Substring(2)
    Dim numericPortion As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(numericPortionString, numericPortion) = False Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid numeric portion", "lastNumber")
    End If

    If numericPortion = 99999 Then
        If letterPortion = "Z"c Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("No more receipt numbers possible", "lastNumber")
        End If

        numericPortion = 0
        letterPortion = letterPortion + Chr(1)

        If letterPortion = "I"c Or letterPortion = "O"c Then
            letterPortion = letterPortion + Chr(1)
        End If
    Else
        numericPortion = numericPortion + 1
    End If

    Return String.Format("G{0}{1:00000}", letterPortion, numericPortion)
End Function
```

I paste it to a Visual Studio 2010 form, and I try to see what happen on `Form_Load`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = GenerateReceiptNumber() '<--HERE IS THE ERROR
End Sub
```

But show me error in `GenerateReceiptNumber()`.

How do I use that code to give me a receipt number in `TextBox1` when I open this form?

The receipt number must be +1 next time with `Form_Load`.

Comment: Which requirements it (receipt number) should follow?

Comment: Could you please provide the full error message?

Comment: Please read the second line of code (the function declaration), and then look at your code that calls it. The reason for the "error" (which you didn't supply, btw) should be very clear. (If it's not, study it until it is - it's really obvious.)

Comment: Why are you creating more than one acccount? http://stackoverflow.com/users/891578/pakkis and http://stackoverflow.com/users/888649/pakkis I've [showed you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016843/how-to-give-unique-number-in-each-receipt-of-payment-in-one-table-of-database-vb/7018213#7018213) the correct way to generate unique receipt-numbers. Do you have still problems getting it going?

Comment: I did it by mistake. Sorry. Delete one of them. (Many problems. Ι apologize from users and admins)

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found my answer to the previous question!

Now, with the solution I provided mr_dunski in the other question, he required that the algorithm create a receipt number based on a previous number. So you need to start with an initial number to begin the sequence:

```
GenerateReceiptNumber(FirstReceiptNumber)
```

or

```
GenerateReceiptNumber("GA00000")
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. It works.!!! Now i try to save this Number to file and next time on Form_Load check who was the last number saved there. Or if you have any good idea how to save last number and check next time to get next number.(I'm new in VS2010).

Comment: For that, you're going to need to look into using a database or a file of some sort. The internet has a great many resources for such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this mode:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = GenerateReceiptNumber("GA00000")
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = GenerateReceiptNumber(FirstReceiptNumber)
End Sub
```